# Dynamically calling methods on interface

Tags: java

I'm a newbie in JAVA programming and i'm trying to write simple MXBean servlet.
I want to to dump some data from RuntimeMXBean.

As you know, there are couple methods for this interface, fe:
- getVmName
- getVmVendor
and more..

I would like to create some array with couple method names and later use foreach to call one-by-one and print its value.

Unfortunately it does not work for me.
I tried obj.invoke, getmethod and nothing - looks like it does not work like regular class or something (sorry, i'm noob)

Some code:

```
RuntimeMXBean rmx = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
```

If i use rmx.getVmVendor() all is fine, but i don't know how can i use (maybe something else?) invoke method with string name on this object (needed for loop)
I'm using latest netbeans with glassfish.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection API:

```
try {
      Method method = rmx.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("aMethodName");
      Object result = method.invoke(rmx);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: I tried it before: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.test.jmx can not access a member of class sun.management.RuntimeImpl with modifiers "public"